# Cannot instantiate an ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, sockets, objectinputstream

i'm trying to instantiate an ObjectInputStream in a client on line 24 but it won't, I can instantiate an ObjectOutputStream but not Input.

```
    private class ClientThread implements Runnable{
    Socket s;
    ObjectInputStream inObject;
    ObjectOutputStream outObject;
    ServerSocket ss;
    Integer portNo;
    ClientThread(int portNo){
        try{
            this.portNo = portNo;
            ss = new ServerSocket(portNo);  
        }               
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("CT : "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void run(){

        boolean hasOpponent = false;
        try{
            while(!hasOpponent){
                s = ss.accept();                                
                if(s != null){
                    inObject = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());   // line 24  
                    System.out.println("1");     
                    hasOpponent = true; 
                    game = new Game(name1, name2);                  
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("D "+ e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: "it won't" doesn't describe the problem. What happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said what does happen but I suspect it is blocking.

ObjectInputStream blocks until it get a header from an ObjectOutputStream which may require a `flush()` from the other end.

Comment: Which implies two things. 1. You must create the ObjectOutoutStream first, at both ends to be safe. 2. You shouldn't create these streams in the accept thread. You should do it in the client-handling thread's run() method.